# close qlistwidget deligate on double click on any item

Tags: qt

I am using a qlistwidget as an deligate inside an cell of Qtreeview.
I have written a handler for the double click on item of qtreelist . Double click handler for Qlistview deligate is working fine.

My requirement is that on double click on any item of qlistwidget deligate for qlistwidget closes.
Please suggest what is the exact signal to be used for it.

Slot for double click on qtreewidgetlist item :---

```
void listWidgetDeligate::onListWidgetItemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem * item)
{

  // emit signal to close the deligate
}
```

Double click handler pass an QListWidgetItem argument to the slot.

How can i use this argument to close the delicate means which signal to emit for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found any appropriate built-in signals for that widget you can always define your own signal in .h file :

```
signals:

void closeOnDoubleClick();
```

If you only need your slot `void listWidgetDeligate::onListWidgetItemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem * item)` to emit another signal and do nothing else, you can just do

```
   connect(<the object of listWidgetDeligate>, 
SIGNAL(<signal that was previously connected to slot onListWidgetItemDoubleClicked>()), 
SIGNAL(closeOnDoubleClick()));
```

that means that your listWidgetDeligate will emit signal `closeOnDoubleClick()` after onListWidgetItemDoubleClicked>() was emitted.

Thus, you do not need a slot.
Remember, that the declared parameters of signal and slot connected to each other must be the same.